# I'm at a loss as to why my question was put on hold because it was "off topic"

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I posted a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51952/identifying-a-post-apocalyptic-movie-perhaps-about-a-world-with-no-women-conta) and it was put on hold as **off-topic** by [Napoleon Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson) on the basis that *"This question does not appear to be about movies or tv within the scope defined in the help centre."* However, I had a look at the [help centre](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and as far as I can tell, there is no stated reason for my question to be marked as off-topic.

How do I get some clarity on this? I know I can just edit it, but I've read over it a couple of times and I truly believe the [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51952/identifying-a-post-apocalyptic-movie-perhaps-about-a-world-with-no-women-conta) is fine. I would like to get this sorted, but as far as I can tell there is no way to directly contact another user to ask.

Any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It was closed because of cross post, it is perfectly on topic but cross post among SE sites are not allowed

Comment: [Refer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/182734) for more details.

Comment: Oh, well that's okay - the "off topic" reason given (probably in error) is what threw me. I actually **want** to delete the other question from scifi.se, but when this one was put on hold I wasn't sure what to do as I was worried I'd lose both of them. If I delete the other one now, what happens to this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why was the question closed?

The question was closed because deliberately [cross-posting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125383/23386) the exact same question to multiple sites by the same user is discouraged. Therefore the slightly newer instance of the question was closed for exactly that reason.

You are right in that your question is not actually off-topic. However, the only way to close a question with a custom message is to close it as off-topic, even if this was admittedly a little inaccurate in your case. Though, in such cases the actual exact close-reason is given in the comments on the question, where *Ankit Sharma* says:

> Cross post are not allowed here, you have to pick one place to ask this. You can keep it on sicfi.se only or can ask for migration here.

## What to do now?

You can either keep your original question at Science Fiction & Fantasy or, if you really want it to be here, you can flag it for migration there, using a custom moderator flag and explaining that you want it migrated here. This will then migrate the question with all its possibly existing answers and we can integrate it into the newer version here.

I understand that this is a little complicated if you are unacquainted with all the intricacies of question migration and cross-posting, but it is ultimately necessary to keep everything in order and not have too diverging simultaneous versions of the same question.

## How to contact a user directly?

If the user has left a comment under your post or made an edit to it, you can just prepend their name with an `@` in a comment. This will actively notify them of your comment.

Otherwise you can also visit [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), esepcially our main chatroom [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) and try to get hold of the user. Especially moderators are quite often around there.

And ultimately, the most fruitful and public way to adress larger unclarities about the rules or the moderators' behaviour and seek input from the community is to bring it to meta as you did here.

## Conclusion

As to your intentions, the original question has been migrated over here and integrated into the newer version. So everything should be sorted out now.

Comment: So, in a nutshell if I ever post a question somewhere and realise later it was probably better asked somewhere else, I should delete it first before asking it again, not afterwards. But, If it's already had some activity, it's better to arrange to have it migrated across instead. Thank you!

Comment: @Monomeeth Basically yes. Though, there are cases where the rules can be a little more fuzzy. If you change the question in a significant way to get the perspective of another site and its different userbase, there can be made a case for both questions staying alive independently. But for the more or less exact same question yeah, migration is the better approach.